# Add a datetime into a log file - CRON TASK

Tags: bash, shell, cron-task

I would like how can i get a log file : my_Log.log who have this infos :

31/07/2017 - 19:05:00 : ok

31/07/2017 - 19:10:00 : ok

31/07/2017 - 19:15:00 : ko

31/07/2017 - 19:20:00 : ok

I've tryed this command :

```
php -f /home/myrepo/Documents/CRON.php | /home/myrepo/Documents/datetime.sh > /home/myrepo/Documents/my_cron.log
```

into my file CRON.php i have this lines :

```
<?php 
echo "ok";
?>
```

into datetime.sh i have these lines :

```
#!/bin/bash

    while read x; do
        echo -n `date +%d/%m/%Y\ %H:%M:%S`;
        echo -n " ";
        echo $x;
    done
```

but into my_cron.log i have just a blank file with nothing inside...

Comment: your script should work, did you try to pipe `ls -l` or something instead of your php script? For me it works

Comment: @Kristianmitk : Yes i try ls -l instead of my php script and it works. Did you know why when i use my php script it didn't work ?

Comment: cannot say if I dont see the content of the file - you could edit your question and add it

Comment: Typical log format is `date '+%b %e %T'`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you could try to add a second '>' in the command.

```
php -f /home/myrepo/Documents/CRON.php | /home/myrepo/Documents/datetime.sh >> /home/myrepo/Documents/my_cron.log
```

In this way you append the output at the file and don't overwrite the previous one.

After that, check the access permission to the scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the precision. I already check the permission of execution of the script and it's executable.